# Why firefox redirecting "localhost:XXXX" to yahoo search page

Tags: firefox, browser

I am facing a very wired problem with my Firefox browser. Whenever i am starting my server and type localhost:9001 in the browser, it always redirect me to the yahoo search page.

[image]

Even I am entering only localhost also, firefix redirecting me to yahoo search page. I think it is because `default search` or may be something else. but it angers me a lot.

I am using Windows 8 OS and it is working fine in Google Chrome. `I had reinstall my browser, but no luck with that also :(`

Please give me some possible solutions so that i can get rid of this issue.

Comment: Firefox is getting confused, it thinks you want to do a search. Try typing it with the protocol, `http://localhost:9001`.

Comment: I tried by typing `http://localhost:9001` also but still redirecting

Comment: Did you actually configure Yahoo to be your search engine? Since you're apparantly OK with "reinstalling the browser", see [Firefox Reset](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems). Also make sure that no pesky third-party installer actually hijacked the default search options or even dropped some add-on

Comment: Try in other browser.

Comment: Impossible to see what OS you are using, but could you try a `ping localhost` in a command window and show the result?  Your OS might not resolve `localhost` properly

Comment: not like that, it is working fine in google chrome

Comment: As I tried with FirFox Reset also, but no luck :(. I am wondering why this things are happening with me only. Anyway I am using Windows 8 Operating System

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still looking for an answer, I had this same problem. I found a spammy add-on installed called "Domain Error Assistant" that was redirecting when domains were not found. Check your add-ons/extensions.

Comment: "Domain Error Assistant" was the problem. Thx.